# Windows Forms: После сворачивания приложения меняется положение формы

Tags: c#, winforms

Имеется форма, для которой в графическом интерфейсе Visual Studio установлено значение `Location = (0,0)`. Однако при запуске программы значение `Location` почему-то меняется на `(-8, -30)`, хотя программно это изменение нигде не прописано. Соответственно из-за этого сдвигаются все элементы, расположенные на форме. Не найдя причины самопроизвольного изменения позиции формы, специально расположил элементы так, чтобы всё выглядело эстетично при значении `Location = (-8, -30)`. Однако когда сворачиваю и разворачиваю программу, значение Location вновь меняется на `(0, 0)`, что снова портит оформление.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в каком направлении копать, чтобы достичь одну из двух целей.

1. Убрать изменение позиции формы на `(0, 0)` при сворачивании/разворачивании (либо принудительно менять это значение на `(-8, -30)`).
2. Сделать так, чтобы значение `Location` было всегда равно `(0, 0)`, как и прописано изначально в `Properties`.

Не уверен, что это влияет на ситуацию, но на всякий случай отмечу, что для этой формы `WindowState = Maximized`. Также было замечено, что если программно прописать, скажем, в `Form_Load` значение `Location` равное `(0,0)`, то простая манипуляция с формой.

```
Form.Hide(); 
Form.Show();
```

Изменит значение `Location` на пресловутое `(-8, -30)`. Ума не приложу, почему.

Answer (score 3):

При `WindowState = Maximized` в `Location` появляются отрицательные значения, т.к. рамки самой формы находятся как бы за пределами экрана. Это поведение системное, и избавиться от него нельзя. На `Location` можно полагаться только если `WindowState = Normal`.

Однако то, что вы затачиваете расположение элементов на форме в зависимости от значения `Location` -- это как-то очень странно. Копайте в направлении избавления от этой зависимости.